# Redirect to new page in JSF 2.0 by clicking on series of bar chart

Tags: jsf-2

I am new to JSF.I am building a xhtml page in which i am displaying a Bar chart.
I wanted to redirect it to new xhtml page using navigation rules when i click on one of the bar of Bar Chart.

Code Sample :

Bar Chart Code:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="south" size="350" resizable="true"
                closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <p:growl id="barChartGrowl" showDetail="true" />
                <p:barChart orientation="vertical" id="tkChart"
                    value="#{chartCreateService.categoryChartModel}"
                    legendPosition="ne" title="Human Capital Model Analysis" minY="0"
                    maxY="100" yaxisLabel="Score" style="height:300px;width:700px"
                    barMargin="50" animate="true">
                    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{userInput.barChartClicked}"
                        update="barChartGrowl" />
                </p:barChart>
            </p:layoutUnit>
```

Bean :

```
public String barChartClicked(ItemSelectEvent event) {
        try {
            System.out.println("In Bar Chart Clicked...");
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                    "Item selected", "Item Index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Series Index:" + event.getSeriesIndex());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            int itemIndex = event.getItemIndex();
            int seriesIndex = event.getSeriesIndex();
            System.out.println("Item Index :"+ itemIndex);
            System.out.println("Series Index :"+ seriesIndex);
            objSummeryAttributeCharts.displaySelectedGroupResults(seriesIndex,itemIndex,objResults,objChart.getCategoryChartModel());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "showAttributeResults";
    }
```

Faces-config Entry :

```
navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/peerGroupAnalysis.jsf</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>showAttributeResults</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/categoryResults.jsf</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Every thing is working fine and i am getting item index and series index of the bar on which user clicked in the bean properly..but it is not redirecting to another page.
Is there any other way to redirect to a new  page in JSF or m i doing something wrong??

Pleas help...

Thanks..

Comment: 10 questions and no answers accepted? You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally navigate on ajax requests, you normally update the dom.
If you need to navigate, you might need to use a redirect, e.g.

> 

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext extContext = ctx.getExternalContext();
String url = extContext.encodeActionURL(ctx.getApplication().getViewHandler().getActionURL(ctx, "/pages/categoryResults.jsf")); 

try {
    extContext.redirect(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried this..but getting an error  "The requested resource (/pages/categoryResults.xhtml) is not available."

Comment: Thanks..its working...))) Just wanted to know one more thing..how can i open this new page in new window or in new tab??

Comment: in this category results page are you just showing something that the user will see and then close and continue using the main window? If so, I would suggest not even using the redirection and just show the results in a dialog